# Detect when Bot is kicked from Guild

Tags: discord-jda

I wish to make the bot doing a REST request after being kicked out from its guild.

Would `onGuildMemberRemove` work on a removal, the bot being the subject of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event you're looking for is [`GuildLeaveEvent`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/events/guild/GuildLeaveEvent.html). The event fires whenever the bot is removed or leaves a guild.